# owncloud 7 set expiration feature

Tags: php, owncloud

We upgraded from owncloud 5.0.10 to owncloud 7.0.4, we found that the set expiration date for shared folder's is not supported anymore from owncloud.

Is there any other way to do this feature?

Comment: If you upgrade to 8.x this feature is definitely available! I could post how to do that for that version if you like?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Just to double check with you, I was talking about private share within user groups and not talking about public share with link.

Comment: Ahhh well in that case you could add a feature for that on github if you like ;)